# How to change DjangoBB idea of a base url?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I've setup an Apache web server with mod_wsgi, and have successfully modified the `basic_project` of DjangoBB to be called from Apache under the site's `/forum/` subtree. The problem I have is that the WSGI app receives (correctly) URLs without the `/forum/` prefix, but produces URLs in the result pages that do not have any prefix.

Example of the issue: opening `http://site/forum/` brings up the start page of the DjangoBB forum; the `Log In` link points to `http://site/account/signin/` instead of the desired `http://site/forum/account/signin`.

How can I make all URLs produced by the DjangoBB app to include a custom prefix (`/forum/` in my case) ?

UPDATE (as requested):

The part of `httpd.conf` that configures the project for use under WSGI:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/forum:/var/www/forum/xforum:/var/www/forum/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /forum /var/www/forum/xforum/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/forum/xforum>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Note that, without including both the project dir (`…/forum/xforum`) and its parent (`…/forum`), the WSGI app didn't work correctly.

Comment: It would help if you pasted your Apache wsgi configuration. Does the prefix disappear for any Django application or just for DjangoBB? For correctly written Django apps, prefixed urls should Just Work as long as `SCRIPT_NAME` is setup correctly.

Comment: Well, I know about FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in `settings.py`, not SCRIPT_NAME, and the issue was I was missing an initial slash in it: `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME= 'forum'`. I changed that into `'/forum'` and it worked. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py` of the project, the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` should be the prefix of the project's URLs *beginning* with a slash (`/`):

In my case, it should be:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/forum'
```